# Domain redirect to URI mod rewrite or 301 redirect?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

What would be the best way to redirect different domains hosted on the same server to a corresponding uri?

Example:

- http://domain1.com to http://domain1.com/index.php/domain1/index
- http://domain2.com to http://domain2.com/index.php/domain2/index
- http://domain3.com to http://domain3.com/index.php/domain3/index

Virtual hosts are not an option since I don't have a
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/site1/ or Directory /var/www/vhosts/site1/

The httpd.conf is minimal since everything is handled via php

In other words, all ..../index.php/domain1/index/ URI's are currently browsable but the user needs to be redirected from domain1.com to ..../index.php/domain1/index/

Comment: when on index i.e / you can get the host from $_SERVER, then parse it so you remove the tld, then just redirect, `header('Location: /index.php/'.$domain.'/index')` there is a pattern in your url, the only difference is the domain name

Comment: Do you really mean "redirect"? Do you want to see `/index.php/domain1/index` in the browser's address bar? Also, why `/index.php/domain1/index` and not `/index.php/domain1/`? And what about other URLs like `/foo/bar`?